Programatically query port # for Wireless ADB?
Every time Wireless Debugging is enabled, its listening port is randomized. Is there an way to programatically identify the current listening port for Wireless ADB connections, such as via a system shell, secure_settings access, or an existing ADB connection?

Please note that this question is referring to the port used for the adb connect command, NOT the adb pair command
